# Trade imbalance at the County level in the US

Tags: data-request, usa, county, trade

I am looking for some source of data on trade imbalance at a county level in the US, preferably for the years 1990-2007. Does anyone know if such data can be publicly available? Or any paper that has been using data like this?

UPD: to break this down, I am looking for:

- international import/export statistics by US county,
- intra-state trade statistics, meaning shipments between counties within the US.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'll find exactly the data you want here because the data available looks quite difficult to explore but I would try the [USA Counties Data File Downloads page of the US Census Bureau](http://www.census.gov/support/USACdataDownloads.html).

[Some counties](http://www.miamidade.gov/business/international-imports-exports.asp) seems to give access to trade data too.

Hope it'll help ;)

Comment: unfortunately, this is not exactly what I am looking for, but anyways thanks for the links - I definitely haven't seen this data before, nice to explore:)